# Selecting multiple fields in win32c.xlPageField

Tags: python-3.x, vba, win32com

Objective: I'm using a python script to generate an excel report (contains lots of pivot tables). 
Problem: Unable to figure out how to add multiple items to pivot table filter

I've figured out a cumbersome solution where I can create individual data sets that are pre-filtered so I don't need to filter them in the pivot table. However, this isn't really efficient or effective if somebody wants to swap the filter on the final excel report.

I'll use code I found online as an example:

```py
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

win32c = win32com.client.constants

wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

TestData = [['Country','Name','Gender','Sign','Amount'],
             ['CH','Max' ,'M','Plus',123.4567],
             ['FR','Max' ,'M','Minus',-23.4567],
             ['CH','Max' ,'M','Plus',12.2314],
             ['SP','Max' ,'M','Minus',-2.2314],
             ['CH','Sam' ,'M','Plus',453.7685],
             ['CH','Sam' ,'M','Minus',-53.7685],
             ['CH','Sara','F','Plus',777.666],
             ['CH','Sara','F','Minus',-77.666],
             ['DE','Hans','M','Plus',345.088],
             ['DE','Hans','M','Minus',-45.088],
             ['DE','Paul','M','Plus',222.455],
             ['DE','Paul','M','Minus',-22.455]]

for i, TestDataRow in enumerate(TestData):
    for j, TestDataItem in enumerate(TestDataRow):
        Sheet1.Cells(i+2,j+4).Value = TestDataItem

cl1 = Sheet1.Cells(2,4)
cl2 = Sheet1.Cells(2+len(TestData)-1,4+len(TestData[0])-1)
PivotSourceRange = Sheet1.Range(cl1,cl2)
PivotSourceRange.Select()
wb.Worksheets.Add()
Sheet2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
cl3=Sheet2.Cells(4,1)
PivotTargetRange=  Sheet2.Range(cl3,cl3)
PivotTableName = 'ReportPivotTable'
PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=PivotSourceRange, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)
PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName=PivotTableName, DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PivotTable.PivotFields('Name').Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Country').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Country').CurrentPage = 'SP'
PivotTable.PivotFields('Gender').Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Sign').Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('Amount'))

Excel.Visible = 1

wb.SaveAs('ranges_and_offsets.xlsx')
Excel.Application.Quit()
```

This generates a pivot table in excel and sets the Country Filter to SP. I know adding the following line will enable the multi selection option.

```py
PivotTable.PivotFields('Country').EnableMultiplePageItems = True
```

At this point, I'm stuck. I would like to find a way to set Country to both SP and DE. I feel like the correct way to do this is to switch .CurrentPage to .CurrentPageList

However, I can't seem to get .CurrentPageList to work

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this maybe too late for this post, but the way I solved this was creating two loops

```
PivotTable.PivotFields(target_column).Position = some_position
PivotTable.PivotFields(target_column).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
for item in show_values:
    PivotTable.PivotFields(target_column).PivotItems(item).Visible = True
for item in excl_values:
    PivotTable.PivotFields(target_column).PivotItems(item).Visible = False
```

I hope it helps!